# "Disk I/O error:" Can not write anything to mounted partitions

Tags: partitioning, mount, 13.04, disk

Recently I have lot of DISK I/O Errors. I am not able to save anything even on my home partition. I have the same problems in 12.04, 12.10 and now in 13.04.
Following is the output of mtab

```
/dev/sda8 / ext4 rw,errors=remount-ro 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev 0 0
none /sys/fs/cgroup tmpfs rw 0 0
none /sys/fs/fuse/connections fusectl rw 0 0
none /sys/kernel/debug debugfs rw 0 0
none /sys/kernel/security securityfs rw 0 0
udev /dev devtmpfs rw,mode=0755 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620 0 0
tmpfs /run tmpfs rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755 0 0
none /run/lock tmpfs rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880 0 0
none /run/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev 0 0
none /run/user tmpfs rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755 0 0
/dev/sda2 /mnt/C fuseblk rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096 0 0
/dev/sda3 /mnt/D fuseblk rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096 0 0
/dev/sda7 /home ext4 rw 0 0
binfmt_misc /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc binfmt_misc rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev 0 0
gvfsd-fuse /run/user/v/gvfs fuse.gvfsd-fuse rw,nosuid,nodev,user=v 0 0
v@t400:~$
```

When I reboot, I get a disk check error message at "Splash Screen". I select "F" to fix the error, and then I am able to resolve the issues.
Skype is the first application to report the error for DISK I/O error.
If I try to take a snapshot of the error shutter does not allow me to save the picture even in my home partition.

Also strangely enough

```
/dev/sda5       300933120   304836607     1951744   82  Linux swap / Solaris    
/dev/sda6       304838656   309637119     2399232   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

I have two swap partitions. Can this happen on its own ? I am sure I never made more than one.

Can any suggest, what must be going wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

Boot a live usb/cd, anything with gparted on it, use it to check the partition, the partition must be unmounted

if it fails your drive may be shot, there are some things you can try if it is a ssd (firmware upgrade/use AHCI mode/ trim)

Answer (score 0):

Take a backup of `/etc/fstab` file

And then change

`/dev/sda8 / ext4 rw,errors=remount-ro 0 0`

to

`/dev/sda8 / ext4 rw,errors=continue 0 0`

and then

`sudo reboot`

Comment: /dev/sda8 is my root. Will it be safe.

Comment: Also strangely enough
/dev/sda5       300933120   304836607     1951744   82  Linux swap / Solaris    
/dev/sda6       304838656   309637119     2399232   82  Linux swap / Solaris    
I have two swap partitions. Can this happen on its own. I am sure I never made more than one.

Comment: I have made the changes, but I am still getting that error frequently.